# How to use rewrite condition to redirect when language prefix is added to URL in multilingual site

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla3.0

Iam running multilingual Joomla web site with 3 languages.
My site was configured not to use language prefix for default language.
I've decide to change this and use language prefix for my default language now.

An example of my current URLs looks like this:

- default:: mysite.com/forum
- english:: mysite.com/en/forum
- slovak::  mysite.com/sk/forum

And I would like to have URLs like this:

- default:: mysite.com/cz/forum
- english:: mysite.com/en/forum
- slovak:: mysite.com/sk/forum

Iam struggling to figure out how to set-up a 301 redirect for default language.
I can not obviously redirect all request after trailing slash, because it would redirect everything.

Is it possible to use rewrite condition in htaccess to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use root `.htaccess` with:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:cz|en|sk)/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+(/.*)?)$ /cz/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: yes, but the /forum link was just an example. I have 100's of URL for default language /category1 /category2 an so on.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, nevertheless it does not work for me. The rule creates infinitive loop every time except the case when cz|en|sk is part of the URI.
The loop contains something like: /usr/www/users/betatn/cz/

Comment: You copy-paste this code, and use only that in your root .htaccess ? Because it redirect to cz... I just add one / now.

Comment: Thank you this works! In my .htaccess there is also another rule (this comes from Joomla .htaccess distribution) 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
` will your redirect rule work with this without any conflict?

Comment: No problem with your rules. They are useful to redirect missing pages to index. Thank you to "accept" my answer...

Comment: Hi I've realised that there is one issue with this rewrite rule. A request to domain on its own `mysite.com/` responds with 303 instead of 301. Other request like: `mysite.com/forum` responds with 301. This is perhaps related to Joomla (some internal redirect to default language) because the 303 redirect works even when I remove RewriteCond you suggested from htaccess. Any ideas?

Comment: This .htaccess can't responds with 303. Just with 301 when rewrite to /cz/ nothing else. But you still have a home page mysite.com/ ? Because if it's not the case, you can change the last rule: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cz/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: I still can not get this right. Requests to naked domain are responded with 303. Is it possible that the path would be set by cookie before .htaccess gets the chance? The 303 redirect is created by Joomla for sure. The Joomla installation resides in root directory, however when you have multi-language site you have an option to either use or skip prefix for default language. When you choose to use prefix for default lang. it creates URLs like this: mysite.com/defaultLanguagePrefix even though you have Joomla installed in root mysite.com. It appears that the path is set in cookie. Any ideas?

Comment: You can try to add redirect (after `RewriteRule ^ - [L]`): `RewriteRule ^$ /cz/ [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add any rule in .htaccess - you go to:

yoursite.com/administrator > Plugins > System - Language Filter > Remove URL Language Code: Set it to No

Now the main (default) language shows with language code as you requested